# Gaussian kernel in OpenCV to generate multiple scales

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sift, gaussianblur

I want to implement an OpenCV version of [VL_PHOW()](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_phow.html) ([matlab src code](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/master/toolbox/sift/vl_phow.m)) from VLFeat. In few words, it's dense SIFT with multiple scales (increasing SIFT descriptor bin size) to make it scale invariant.

However, the authors suggests to apply a Gaussian kernel to improve the results. In paritcular, the `Magnif` parameter describe it:

> Magnif 6 The image is smoothed by a Gaussian kernel of standard
>   deviation SIZE / MAGNIF. Note that, in the standard SIFT descriptor,
>   the magnification value is 3; here the default one is 6 as it seems to
>   perform better in applications.

And this is the relevant matlab code:

```
% smooth the image to the appropriate scale based on the size
% of the SIFT bins
sigma = opts.sizes(si) / opts.magnif ;
ims = vl_imsmooth(im, sigma) ;
```

My question is: how can I implement this in OpenCV? The equivalent function in OpenCV seems to be [GaussianBlur](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#gaussianblur), but I can't figure out how to represent the code above in terms of this function.

Comment: `GaussianBlur(in, out, Size(), sigma)`

Comment: @Miki Oh well, that was easy :) I'm sorry, but I never used `GaussianBlur` and it's always difficult to detect wrong settings.